# PROBLEMAS AL GENERAR JAR EN NETBEANS

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, jar

me ha surgido un problema y es que al darle al botón clean and build project para generar el archivo java me salta el siguiente error:

```
ant -f C:\\aplicacion -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Created dir: C:\aplicacion\build
Updating property file: C:\aplicacion\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\aplicacion\build
C:\aplicacion\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1394: Unable to delete file C:\aplicacion\dist\aplicacion.jar
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

¿Alguién podría ayudarme?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo más probable es que tu programa no haya dejado de correr, por lo que ant te impide borrarlo. Termina tu corrida con el botón de stop o reinicia tu ide si no ves el proceso, con eso debería de bastar

Comment: Gracias ya lo he solucionado. El problema venia que después de tener el jar bien montado, he tenido que desintalar la maquina virtual de java, por que no me dejaba ejecutar el jar, y volverla a instalar a parte de meterle solo la primera vez por linea de comando java -jar nombre.jar para poder ejecutar el archivo una vez hecho esto ya me funcionaba todo con normalidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema venia que después de tener el jar bien montado, he tenido que desintalar la maquina virtual de java, por que no me dejaba ejecutar el jar, y volverla a instalar a parte de meterle solo la primera vez por linea de comando java -jar nombre.jar para poder ejecutar el archivo una vez hecho esto ya me funcionaba todo con normalidad.